# ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm encountering an issue with my Python code while trying to import TensorFlow and Keras modules in my project. When attempting to execute the code, I receive the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:/Users/X/gitHub/n/layer2/train.py", line 6, in 
> from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint
> File "C:\Users\X\gitHub\n\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras_*init*_.py", line 21, in 
> from keras import models
> File "C:\Users\X\gitHub\n\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\models_*init*_.py", line 18, in 
> from keras.engine.functional import Functional
> File "C:\Users\X\gitHub\n\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 24, in 
> import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'

**Steps Taken:**

1. Checked the TensorFlow and Keras versions installed in my environment.
2. Reviewed the code and verified the import statements.

**Code Snippet:**

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint
# Other relevant import statements
```

**Expected Outcome:**

I anticipated the code to import the necessary TensorFlow and Keras modules without any errors. However, the 'No module named 'tensorflow.compat'' error occurred, preventing successful execution.

**Request:**

I would appreciate guidance on how to resolve this issue. Is there a workaround or an alternative import statement for the tensorflow.compat.v2 module in TensorFlow 2.x? Or should I consider downgrading TensorFlow to a version that supports this import?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be incredibly helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You are using incompatible Keras and TensorFlow versions, so yes you have to downgrade to a TensorFlow version that is supported by your Keras version, and also, you could have found this by searching the site (there are many many questions about this error).